# Run Node Js on iis localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, iis

how to run `node js` on `iis` localhost port 80?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't run node.js on IIS, would be like trying to run apache on IIS, node.js is doing the HTTP request/response handling.

What you are really looking for (or at least what it sounds like based on your question) is to run js files server side on IIS, which I don't think is currently provided.

However if you want to know how to run your application using port 80, just make sure nothing is using this port and setup your application to listen on that port.

```
var net = require('net');
//do stuff
var server = server.createServer();
//do some other stuff
server.listen(80);
//do more stuff
```